# How to find matching elements in 2 tensors of different sizes?

Tags: tensorflow, compare

I am trying to achieve something very simple in Tensorflow (and not native Python or NumPy or pandas) which can be done in any of the following ways:

1. Have 2 separate arrays/tensors with different sizes. Each element holds two values: a comparing-value and a weight. We want to compare the comparing-value in both tensors, and multiply their corresponding weights.
2. Have comparing-value and weights as different arrays. Then compare the comparing-values, get the indices, then use the index to find elements in the weight vectors and then multiply them.

**In short I want to find indices of matching elements in  both the tensors.**

The closest solution I could find is to convert them to sets, but it does not give the exact index of the element.

I was able to achieve what I wanted using Pandas:

`matched = pd.Index(v1).intersection(pd.Index(v2))`

and native Python:

`ind_v1, ind_v2 = [i for i, item in enumerate(v1_1) if item in v2_1],[i for i, item in enumerate(v2_1) if item in v1_1]`

I wish to have this same in Tensorflow.

Comment: you should provide some code or some tries you've done in order to be helped. Please read carefully https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before posting

Comment: Edited with code...